# How to avoid downloadable files being blocked by Windows?

Tags: windows-10, download, internet-security

I am maintaining a commercial web site and delivering a product via a download area. The files are free of access and intended as a promotional means for the product. This is a critical element of my business.

With the evolution of Windows versions, though, user downloads are more and more controlled, and my files are systematically reported as unsafe (there are .msi and .chm files). To the extent that it becomes virtually impossible to get those files (well if you know how to, you can, via a very complex route, and ignoring a number of scary warnings).

Microsoft offers the possibility to report the files as safe, but this is tedious and not always works.

So my question: is there a way to obtain some permanent status/recognition with Microsoft such that these downloads are no more considered harmful ? Or some other workaround ?

Comment: To my experience Windows defender only has "problems" with unsigned MSI files. Therefore you may consider buying a code signing certificate and sign all the MSI files provided for download.

Comment: @Robert: thanks Robert, I begin to understand the topic. Where do I buy a code certificate ? Microsoft or any CA ? (Not asking for a recommendation, just want to know what is possible.)

Comment: Any CA that is present in Windows is suitable for issuing such a certificate. Just look for "Microsoft Authenticode Code Signing Certificate".

Comment: @Robert: thanks a lot.